# Dynamic Link not opening web browser url

Tags: android-studio, firebase-dynamic-links

So when opening the dynamic link I get the error- Requested URL must be a parseable URI, but possibly incomplete to be a DynamicLink.

I have the app store link attached to it. How do I fix this?
Say my dynamic link is https://example.page.link and my URL is https://example.page.link/abcd.

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://exmaple.page.link/"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.page.link/")
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            .buildDynamicLink();
dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
```

But when I add abcd in setDomainUriPrefix() then the post in the app doesn't open, though the link opens in the browser.

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://exmaple.page.link/"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.page.link/abcd")
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            .buildDynamicLink();
```

And when I receive this link, the url always shows as the playstore link, hence it doesn't open the app post. How can I fix this?
    dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();